# Unable to invoke Webdriver Error while Creating a Session performance testing with Jmeter

Tags: performance, selenium-webdriver, jmeter, webdriver, webdriver-manager

I have situation of i'm starting a Jmeter test, its invoking empty driver ,getting error unable to create a session.. error log is ..
ERROR o.a.j.t. JMeterThread: Error calling threadStarted nqa.selenium. Session NotCreatedException: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 114

browser version is 116.0.5845.97 with binary path C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

nfo: version: '3.14.0', revision: 'aacccce0', time: '2018-08-02T20:19:58.91Z'

info: host: 'jmeter-node', ip: '10.10.181.140', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: 1.8.0_261'

info: driver.version: ChromeDriver

stacktrace: Backtrace:

GetHandleVerifier [0x0106A813+48355]

(No symbol) [0x00FFC4B1] (No symbol) [0x00F05358]

(No symbol) [0x00F261AC]

(No symbol) [0x00F21EF3]

(No symbol) [0x00F20579]

(No symbol) [0x00F50C55]

(No symbol) [0x00F5093C]

(No symbol) [0x00F4A536]

(No symbol) [0x00F282DC]

(No symbol) [0x00F293DD]

GetHandleVerifier [0x012CAABD+2539405]

GetHandleVerifier [0x0130A78F+2800735]

GetHandleVerifier [0x0130456C+2775612]

GetHandleVerifier [0x010F51E0+616112]

(No symbol) [0x01005F8C]

(No symbol) [0x01002328]

(No symbol) [0x0100240B]

(No symbol) [0x00FF4FF7]

BaseThreadInitThunk [0x75E900C9+25] Rt1GetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x76F37B1E+286]

RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x76F37AEE+238]

at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_261] at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_261]

at org.openqa.selenium.remote.W3CHandshakeResponse.lambda$new$0 (W3CHandshakeResponse.java:57) ~[selenium-remote-driver-3.14.0.jar:?]

at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_261] at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_261]

Answer (score 0):

Do you want us to help you to understand this stanza:

> This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 114

It means that there is a mismatch between Chrome browser and [Chromedriver](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/), you either need to downgrade your Chrome to 114 or to upgrade your [ChromeDriver to 116](https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/)

Also Selenium 3.14.0 is kind of outdated, current latest version of the WebDriver Sampler is [4.10.0](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/kg.apc/jmeter-plugins-webdriver/4.10.0.0) and it matches the relevant Selenium version so consider upgrading. It cen be done using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-plugins-manager)